# Accessing an SQL Server stored procedure (containing no SELECT statement) from Excel VBA, ideally without using Excel Data Connections?

Tags: sql-server, vba

I'm trying to build a VBA form that runs a SQL Server stored procedure to cache data before it does anything else.  Ideally I'd prefer not to use an Excel data connection because then I can't export it to a new workbook with a minimum of fuss - it'd be nice to contain all of the information in the form's file.

The main way I know to connect VBA to a database is using code along these lines:

```
Dim cnn As New ADODB.Connection
Dim rst As New ADODB.Recordset
cnn.Open ConnectionString
rst.Open QueryText, cnn, adOpenDynamic

/*Whatever you're doing to the data goes here*/

rst.Close
cnn.Close
```

The problem I'm running into is that the caching proc doesn't return a dataset (not even a blank one), and this type of connection seems to throw a tizzy if there is no data returned.  And I'd prefer not to modify the proc if I don't have to.

Is there a feasible solution, within these constraints?  Or am I just being too whiny and should suck it up and use an Excel data connection or something?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you are looking for an ADODB.Command. Try something like this:

```
Dim cnn As New ADODB.Connection
Dim cmd As ADODB.Command

cnn.Open ConnectionString
Set cmd = New ADODB.Command

With cmd
    .ActiveConnection = cnn
    .CommandText = "EXEC spNameHere param1"
    .CommandType = adCmdText
    .Execute
End With
```